# Python Batch Append To files of a Certain Type - in a Single Directory

Tags: python, batch-file

apologies if this has already been shown how to do.

I am trying to batch process some files in Python

I need to append a string to the end of a list of html files in a folder.

So the steps are:

1. Open all files in folder
2. Append a string - At the bottom of each file add the string)
3. Close files

I have had a look at some of the solutions on stack exchange but I keep getting syntax errors.

Have not used python in a while hence a bit rusty.

```
import os
for file in os.listdir("c:\Users\a\Desktop\New"):
if file.endswith(".html"):
   appendString = "\ add this string to end of file"
   appendFile.write = (appendString)
   apendFile.close()
```

I'm sure it something simple.

Please advise many thanks!

**apologies my code has errors as I had a lot of files open and its been a long day!

Edit:
Also the files already have content in them that need to be preserved. 
I would like to simply add the sample text at the bottom of each file.

Comment: What's `appendFile`? Also you have indentation problems

Comment: I think you may need to open the file so you need in line 4, "with open(file) as appendFile:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your bit of code is missing several things (indentation, definition of appendFile, plus typo).

What about:

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir("c:\Users\a\Desktop\New"): # filename is a string
    if filename.endswith(".html"): # notice the indent
        appendFile = open(filename, 'a') # file object, notice 'a' mode
        appendString = "\ add this string to end of file" # could be done out of the loop if constant
        appendFile.write(appendString)
        appendFile.close()
```

Important: better not to use `file` as a variable name as it is also the name of a builtin function in python2.7 (similar to `open`).

You can also use the `with` construct to do the closing for you (see Celeo's answer).

Comment: Yes apologies I have been doing this in haste, I had like 20 files open. Let me fiddle about with this - thank you.

Comment: Hi Francis, thank you  - the new files being out put only have the string in it. The original content of the files is not being preserved.

Comment: That's surprising if you open the file in append mode with `'a'` as suggested.

Answer (score 1):

You go from using `file` to `appendFile`, but your code doesn't show you having setting it up.

```
import os

for file in os.listdir("c:\\Users\\a\\Desktop\\New"):
    if file.endswith(".html"):
        appendString = "\ add this string to end of file"
        with open(file, 'a') as appendFile:
            appendFile.write(appendString)
```

[Docs link for file I/O](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/inputoutput.html)

Comment: Hi Celeo, thankyou I have tested this and it outputs the files with the string added. However same issue as mentioned above. The original file contents are not being preserved. Also can you advise on how I can output all the files to a folder so they don't take over the whole desktop. Thank you!

Comment: As seen [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#open), opening the file through `open` with mode '*a*' opens it in append mode (unless that file doesn't exist!) so text is added to the end. If you need to move files, check out [shutil.move](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/shutil.html#shutil.move).

Answer (score 0):

`glob` gives you a list of paths to files which match the given glob expression. In your case, you want anything that ends in `.html` (i.e. `*.html`) in a certain directory.

Once you've gotten these filepaths, then appending text to them is quite simple

```
import glob
import os

dirpath = 'directory/with/html/files'
appendStr = 'this string will be appended'

for fpath in glob.glob(os.path.join(dirpath, "*.html")):
    with open(fpath, 'a') as outfile:
        outfile.write(appendStr)
```

Comment: FYI I saw this in the Low Quality queue. Its correct, but you might want to add some explanation so it doesn't get deleted by over-zealous reviewers.